# pushed view should appear with transparent background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, pushviewcontroller

I am just pushing another view from one view .
the pushed view would appear transparent after this code . 
i have used it many times earlier . it is as simple as this .

```
settings *set = [[settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"settings" bundle:nil];
set.view.backgroundColor = [ [UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:set animated:YES ];
```

But now with latest `ios` and `xcode` ,
pushed view does not become transparent anymore .
so if anyone has any other solution for this then please let me know .

I already referred many posts regarding this like

- http://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/
- [Setting alpha on UIView sets the alpha on its subviews which should not happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681901/setting-alpha-on-uiview-sets-the-alpha-on-its-subviews-which-should-not-happen)
- [Custom UI: Popup in iOS Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298100/custom-ui-popup-in-ios-objective-c)
- [Setting alpha on UIView sets the alpha on its subviews which should not happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681901/setting-alpha-on-uiview-sets-the-alpha-on-its-subviews-which-should-not-happen)

and asked to many other members , but could not get the solution for this issue . [image: this is page 1][image: this is pushed page]

Comment: First, write question with proper formatting! And hows your pushed view looks ? add screenshot in question if possible!

Comment: add this line in viewDidLoad of setting . self.view.backgroundColor = [ [UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];

Comment: it does not work @KKRocks .

Comment: Add line: self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: @Lion i have added screen shots . you can see that 1st page should be visible in background . but it is not here . i have used this many times before , but this time it is not working .

Comment: @ninjaproger i have tried that . it did not work .

Comment: --> TViewController *push = [[TViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TViewController" bundle:nil ];  
   -->  self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
 -->   push.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:127.0f/255.0f alpha:0.6f] ;
 
-->    [self.navigationController pushViewController:push animated:YES];
i have tried this also . but no use .

Answer (score 1):

You should present your `view controller` instead of `push`, because with push, you can not achieve transparency that shows previous view controller!

You can debug view hierarchy to just check that how much views are between your top view and previous view.

To debug view hierarchy you can tap `Debug View Hierarchy` button [image] from debug area!

Comment: on pushed page there are other 3 views hierarchy between uiwindow and uiview . those are UiLayoutContainerView , UiNavigationTransitionView , UiViewcontrollerWrapperView . .. so you are saying that , to make uiview tranparent , we have to make all those in between 3 views transparent too , is it ?

Comment: yeah! may be i think! I haven't tried this kind of stuff but all view should have clear color which are stays between! I suggest you to present view controller instead of push!

Comment: good approach . i ll try with present view also . but i was using these kinda coding before many times . i never faced problems before regarding this issue .

Comment: sorry for late reply , i have tried presenting view controller instead of push . but the answer is same . i did not work .